# Java Help: Character Encoding Help - int to String

Tags: java, character-encoding, abstract-class, outputstream, printwriter

I am trying to use the write(int) method of java.io.OutputStream, and I can't figure out how to convert the int back into a String correctly.

```
public PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStream() {

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        outputField.setText(/* I need a byte[] or char[] or string from this int */);
    }

});
```

I really need assistance with this. I tried to use a method to make a byte[] from an int but it made the text messed up with lots of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
outputField.setText(""+b);
```

or

```
outputField.setText(Integer.valueOf(b).toString());
```

Comment: Or simply `outputField.setText(Integer.toString(b))`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very odd to be directing an OutputStream to what appears to be a text field in a GUI of some kind. Are you sure that's what you really want? If you want to capture something being written to a Writer, a [StringWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) is usually appropriate. You just let the writing happen, then call [toString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#toString%28%29) on it to get the final result. If you really *are* looking for a way to write stuff to a text field as it's written to a Writer/OutputStream, then check this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("I be streamin!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    frame.add(field);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Enter stuff to write to the field");
    char c;
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8");
    while ((c = (char) in.read()) != -1) {
        String currentText = field.getText();
        field.setText(currentText + c);
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
}
```

Note 1: Use the right encoding in place of UTF-8.

Note 2: While I slowed this down with a Thread.sleep(), writing a character at a time to a field is somewhat wasteful in itself because you're constantly creating and throwing away Strings. Doing some small amount of buffering, like using a StringWriter as I mentioned earlier, might be a better approach unless you're after the "live feed" feel of having stuff appear as it's read in.